# Different response geocoding in PHP than directly in URL navigation bar (Google maps api v3 json)

Tags: php, json, google-maps, geocoding

If I put this URL: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=la%20coru%C3%B1a,%20la%20coru%C3%B1a,%20espa%C3%B1a&sensor=false&region=es

I get this json object:

```
{   "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "A Coruña",
           "short_name" : "A Coruña",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        }, etc...
```

But if I try it with PHP:

```
<?php $address = urlencode("la coruña, la coruña, España"); $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false&region=es'); echo "<pre>"; print_r($geocode); echo "</pre>";?>
```

The response is not equal.

You can see that it's not equal: Corunna != Coruña

I have been dealing with UTF-8 but I don't get a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the `region`, but that causes region biasing, but doesn't affect the output language.  For that, you need to specify the `language` parameter. From the [API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests):

- > **language** (optional) — If **language** is not supplied, the geocoder will attempt to use the native language of the domain from
  >   which the request is sent wherever possible.

I would guess that the server that runs the PHP code is in a different country than you are (or Google thinks it is). That's why you get different results when requesting from the server and requesting from your browser.

In fact, when I click on the url you provide, I get the english version ("Corunna") output, presumably because I am in the United States. If I add `&language=es` to the url I get the spanish version ("A Coruña").

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!
You save me!! really, thanks a lot!